# What does Mr Bean have to do with Adar?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

We all know the famous Gemara:

### משנכנס אדר *מר* *בין* בשמחה

Or to summarize it in a picture (*if this is allowed on Mi Yodea*):

[image: Mr Bean Purim Adar]

What connection has Mr Bean with Adar and Simcha?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 7):

You are unfortunately reading the word Bean when the correct pronunciation is Bin - like Yehoshua Bin Nun. Mr Bin who was recently serialized in Riva Pomerantz's story in Family First is an individual who has severe ADHD. When Adar rolls in he is very happy as that is when he finally realized how his issues are messing him up and was able to correct them. Due to that every year he is B'Simcha in Adar.

Comment: Bravo bravo. That is impressive

Comment: Ha ha :) (15 Chars)

Answer (score 6):

In Adar it is customary to make bad jokes, usually dry in nature and witty. Like British humor. I would assume that is the connection between Adar and the comedy of Mr. Bean. Thus he is happy at the arrival of Adar, for perhaps he gets a bump in sales of his comedy material.

Comment: I don't know why I'm not surprised ...

Comment: Love the joke though

Comment: Not mine, but i thought it deserved a place here.