# PTIJ: Who is Marvin And why is he happy

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

We say מי שנכנס אדר מרבין בשמחה *When Adar comes in Marvin is happy*. Who is Marvin and why is he so happy?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

---

This is not the same question as it uses the name Marvin and the other question has the pun on Adar.

Comment: http://mi.yodeya.com/a/89419

Comment: @DoubleAA Different question. I am asking about Marvin.

Comment: Close enough imo, but anyway I was pointing out msh's answer

Comment: I'm with doubleAA, msh210 already made the joke and answered this question before it was asked. I realize people will be mad that I'm trying to close PTIJ as a dupe, but as this joke was already made, I'm voting to close.

Comment: @DoubleAA shows what procrastinating can do I had meant to ask before but didn't get a round toit

Comment: Marvin, or [Mr Bean](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55256/what-does-mr-bean-have-to-do-with-adar)?

Answer (score 7):

Originally, Marvin wasn't Jewish, as the Gemara in Sanhedrin 88b relates:

> תניא אמר רבי יוסי מתחילה לא היו מרבין מחלוקת בישראל
>
> R' Yose said: Originally, Marvin wasn't of the divisions of Israel

However, at the end of the Purim story, Marvin became Jewish, as it says (Ester 8:17)

> ובכל מדינה ומדינה ובכל עיר ועיר... ורבים מעמי הארץ מתיהדים
>
> In every province and in every city ... many of the people became Jewish

and there's no such thing as a city without Marvin, as the Talmud says (Sanhedrin 112a):

> ואי אתה מוציא כל העיר כולה לשעריך אלא מרבין
>
> You never find "every city" without Marvin

Therefore, Marvin joyfully remembers the season in which, amongst much celebration, he joined the Jewish people.

Answer (score 1):

Marvin Rubnikov is the leader of a NYC local music band called *Marvin Besimcha*. He is always happy because he plays music at weddings and B'nai Mitvah throughout the NY / NJ / CT area.

During this time of year, he is exceptionally happy, and not just because it's Adar. There is a marked increase of weddings during Adar because many want to be married before *sefira* begins as well as not being married to close to Pesach when people are busy with Pesach cleaning and buying. Marvin knows this, so he books loads of events now. And the additional money helps Marvin pay his Pesach bills.

Answer (score -2):

i am marvin. i am also jewish. therfor you can make me happy by sending me money on purim.